# Is there any function to get the original coordinates of a point after a rotation?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation

Imagine that I have an object, like a rectangle which is

```
width : 500
height : 200
```

the original coordinates are :

```
x = 300
y = 200
```

But if I applies an angle of **178.02°** the coordinates are now :

```
x = 503.4
y = 396.48
```

My question is, just by knowing theses information, like the new position, the angle applied and the size of the object, is it possible to know where was the `x` and `y` point located **before** the rotation ?
Thanks

Comment: you could store the point before

Comment: I can't, I got the informations from a JSON file and it's not stored anywhere.

Comment: Do you also know the center of rotation? E.g. if the rotation was around the center of the rectangle, do you know that center?

Comment: Your question indicates you are the one applying the translation, is that correct?

Comment: @JohanC No I don't, because I only have the end position and the angle applied. I can't base on the center, because the position is not good

Comment: Well, the original coordinates can be anywhere on a circle centered around x,y and with radius `2*R*sin(angle/2)` with `R` the original radius of the rotation and `angle` the rotated angle.

Comment: Forgive me for my question, but let me understand. Given the 500x200 rectangle, (300, 200) are coordinates.. of what? One of the vertexes? A generic point inside the rectangle? And what is the original position of the rectangle? Lower lefte vertex on (0,0)? And what is the center of the rotation?